# How to I match the first phrase until there is a dash mark using Regex

Tags: regex

I have several strings (product descriptions) that look like this:

product_one.txt:

***Computer*** - Intel i7, 2.44GHz, 60GB RAM, ...

product_two.txt:

***Laptop*** - Intel i5, 2.3GHz, 8GB RAM, ...

product_three.txt:

***Smartphone*** - Qualcome 8.3, 2.0GHz, 4GB RAM, ...

I keep every string in a separated file. Now, I would like to match the product type of each product (computer, laptop or smartphone) - these words in bold.

So, I have each of my string in its .txt file. I have written an app in Java that takes each .txt file and exports the product type of each product based on the regular expression I have trouble with.

Comment: *several strings* or several files?

Comment: I have each of my string in its .txt file. I have written an app in Java that takes each .txt file and exports the product type of each product based on the regular expression I have trouble with.

Comment: so split the string by space and get the first chunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex could be:

```
^\\w+
```

That is an anchor matching the start of the string and at least one (possibly more) word characters.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QctoQj/1) and note that you need two backward slashes in `Java`, hence the difference between the demo and the expression above.